# Перемещение QGroupBox в пределах одной формы

Tags: c++, qt5, drag-n-drop

Задача простая но не нашел адекватного решения. У меня есть QTabWidget и на одной из вкладок будет набор QGroupBox'ов, которые пользователь должен иметь возможность потаскать в пределах этой вкладки в любую точку. Если есть простое решение, пожалуйста, подскажите

Comment: 1) укажите в метке какой язык, например c++, python, java 2) расскажите, зачем вам это нужно, мб проще будет через графическую сцену сделать?

Comment: @gil9red, в данной вкладке QGroupBox'ы содержат информацию о классах выбранного проекта (аналог диаграммы классов из uml). Соответственно пользователю надо дать возможность размещать эти QGroupBox'ы так, как ему будет удобно

Comment: Смотрели в сторону QGraphicsScene? Там и виджеты можно помещать, просто перемещать и т.п. Если без сцены делать, то размещаете QGroupBox через указание parent'а, т.е. без layout'ом, тогда виджет можно перемещать через метод move. Т.е. нужно будет или фильтр событий повесить на виджет и ловить на нем события мышки, и вручную его перемещать, либо создать наследника и в нем переопределить события мышки: mouseMoveEvent, mousePressEvent и mouseReleaseEvent

Comment: @gil9red, спасибо, посмотрю qgraphicscene, как-то забыл о сцене